# @RequestMapping with slashes fails to return a view

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a stupid problem I have no idea why this is happening - view resolution fails if I have slashes in my mapping; I have this controller:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class PartialsController {

  @RequestMapping ("/views/partials/{view}") // Doesn't work!
  public String partial (@PathVariable ("view") String view) {
    System.out.println ("\n\nVIEW=\"" + view + "\"\n\n");
    return "partials/" + view;
  }

  @RequestMapping ("/partial-{view}-view") // Works!!!
  public String test (@PathVariable ("view") String view) {
    return partial (view);
  }

  @RequestMapping ("/views/partials/{view}/show.html") // Doesn't work!
  public String test2 (@PathVariable ("view") String view) {
    return partial (view);
  }
}
```

Full stack trace is here: http://pastebin.com/CXwYd9i3 here's the top of it (I see my system.out in every case):

```
[DEBUG] : Could not complete request
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:205)
at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:171)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:474)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
    ...
```

I'd really like to use the first method, it just makes more sense for what I'm doing; much thanks in advance for any help!

P.S. Forgot to add, this is my Java Config:

```
@Override
public void onStartup (ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext mvcContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ();
  mvcContext.register (MvcConfiguration.class);
  Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet ("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet (mvcContext));
  dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup (1);
  dispatcher.addMapping ("/");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out, typing up a response made me think that something was wrong with my set up of the JSP view resolver and indeed there was:

```
@Bean (name = "jspViewResolver")
public ViewResolver jspViewResolver () {
  return new InternalResourceViewResolver () {
    {
      setPrefix ("/META-INF/resources/mev/views/");
      setSuffix (".jsp");
      setOrder (2);
      setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes (true);
    }
  };
}
```

I didn't have a leading slash before the META-INF. Yeah I have my views in a weird spot. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 @Override
public void onStartup (ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext mvcContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ();
  mvcContext.register (MvcConfiguration.class);
  Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet ("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet (mvcContext));
  dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup (1);
  dispatcher.addMapping ("/*"); //<- It will dispatch all URLs, not only those which starts with /
}
```

Comment: I tried that, I'm just getting a straight up 404 then - no mapping found. It makes sense to me too since I think the star means all mappings until another slash. The problem isn't multiple slashes in the mapping per se, it's in conjunction with a view as I have mappings with multiple slashes elsewhere in the app returning JSON (@ResponseBody so no view resolution takes place) and everything works just fine, and also the controller with the slashes does get called, I do see whatever logging I put in it, so whatever goes wrong goes wrong after it comes back from the controller.